# Component library in react.js with scss and webpack

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I am creating my own component library with React.js and scss, which can be used across multiple
react projects. I am using webpack to bundle the components.
i have modularized my module to import individual components specifically.

```
import Button from '@myModule/button';
```

When i bundle them with webpack, i get css and js separate. So at the consuming application i have to import the main.css file globally, and button component separately. Can i tie the button related styles(button.scss) also to the button.js file, so that, importing the button component will have its styles defined within.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your webpack configuration, you can add the component-specific styles with an import in the component file.

Here is what you may need in the rules of your webpack entry:

```
{
 test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
   { loader: 'style-loader' },
   { loader: 'css-loader' },
   { loader: 'sass-loader' },
  ]
}
```

Also add '.scss' in the `resolve.extensions` array.

Then in your Button.jsx file you can do:

```
import './button.scss';
```

Comment: Yea. I have included the button.scss in button.js file already. My problem is i want to package this as component library, and distribute through npm. While requiring at the new application, i want to package the styles inside component itself, do i dont have to require the styles globally..

Comment: Maybe I don't get the question right, but if you have imported the styles into the component, the client of your library wouldn't need to import that same stylesheet.